# Get user Seesion id from SugarCRM using Email ID/User Id

Tags: authentication, sugarcrm

I have one sugarCRM installation. When I pass the email id/user id, is it possible to9 get the user session id in sugarCRM?

Please suggest.Because based on user identity I need to create Leads,   campaigns etc using REST API

Answer (score 0):

Logged in user details are store in global variable current_user.
And Yes. You will get session id once you call login method from REST.
$proxy is the object of your rest

```
$credentials = array(    
'user_name' => 'username',    
'password' => md5('password')     
);

$result = $proxy->login($credentials, 'your_application_name');   
$session_id = $result['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Sachin is right, there is a global variable for currently logged in user.
And you can access its properties straightforward : 
Its an instance of the user bean.

```
global $current_user;
echo $current_user->id;
echo $current_user->user_name;
```